# Code taking too much time for normalisation and Apply function in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

this is just sample data with my code. i want to normalization the total column in other column. currently i have around 2000 groups for that its taking 15 mins for normalisation and fgroup.

what are the ways to reduce the time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)
n = 1500000

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['group'] = np.random.randint(1700, size=n)
df['ID'] = np.random.randint(5, size=n)
df['Total'] = np.random.randint(400, size=n)
df['Normalized_total'] = df.groupby('group')['Total'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()- x.min()))

def norm_group(df):
    if df['Normalized_total'] > 0.70 and df['group'] > 100 and df['ID'] > 3:
        return 3
    elif df['Normalized_total'] > 0.5 and df['group'] < 100 and df['ID'] < 3:
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

df['fgroup'] = df.apply(norm_group, axis=1)
```

Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't take 15 minutes to run, even with 2000 groups.  How long is your actual dataframe (number of rows, I mean)?  If I crank n up to 15 M and leave ngroups=1700, it still only takes 6 seconds for me (which isn't speedy, I'll admit, but a far cry from 15 minutes.)

Comment: in my original dataset i have 2000 groups. shape of dataframe is (1200000, 40). idont know why its taking too much time for this piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it on a frame of that size and it took less than a second.   What are the dtypes of the columns of the real data?

Comment: 30 columns are objects and 5 columns are int and rest are floats.

Comment: Wait, you've edited the code.  Are you saying that it's actually the `df.apply`, which wasn't even in your original code, which is the slow bit?

Comment: @DSM yes. df.apply is taking much time

Answer (score 1):

You can using `transform` and define your own function

```
%timeit df['Normalized_total'] = df.groupby('group')['Total'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()- x.min()))
1 loop, best of 3: 508 ms per loop

# below is my solution
def myfunc():
    g=df.groupby('group')['Total']
    return df['Total']-g.transform('min')/g.transform(np.ptp)
%timeit myfunc()
1 loop, best of 3: 398 ms per loop
```

Comment: i have edited my question can you please look into it.